# Why mongoose doesn't update document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem with updating a document using mongoose. It doesn't update the document when I call `.update()`.
index.html

```
<form method="POST" action="/updateItem?_method=PUT">
    <input type="text" name="itemName" placeholder="Update Item" required/>
    <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="price"/>
    <input type="text" name="rarity" placeholder="rarity"/>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

app.js(server-side)

```
app.put("/updateItem", (req, res)=>{
    var updatedObj ={};
    Object.entries(req.body).forEach(elem=>{
        if(elem[0]!=="itemName"){
            updatedObj[elem[0]] = elem[1];
        };
    });
    console.log(updatedObj);
    async function updateItem(){
        const updatedItem = await Item.update({name:req.body.itemName}, {
            $set: updatedObj
        });
        console.log(updatedItem);
        res.redirect(`/searchItem?itemName=${req.body.itemName}`);
    };
    updateItem();

});
```

Item mongoose model:

```
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
```

I have two other questions that are not entirely related to my problem, so it's not very important to answer them, but it will be of huge help.

1. What happens if i included the name of Item in `updatedObj` while updating?
2. What happens if i try to update a non-existant item? Does mongoose create a new one?Or does it return an error?

Comment: Is that **ALL** of the schema? As in just **one** field called `name`? If so then there is basically nothing to update. Mongoose removes any fields that do not match the "schema". Are you perhaps attempting to **dynamically** assign new fields to a document without knowing what they are and therefore not defining them in the schema?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to add some fields that don't exist before in the schema

Comment: I saw the question you linked, but i am not creating a new Item. I am updating an existant Item with fields that do not exist in the schema. I tried the `{strict:false}` but the fields don't add to the existant Item.

Comment: Well aware you are updating and the `{ strict: false }` of course applies to ANY operations and not just new items. The rest of us don't see a reproduction of your claim since adding that option essentially bypasses all schema validation for present fields and you can simply add what you want. I suggest you actually show in your question what you "tried" since you can only be implementing the correct solution incorrectly. Works for the rest of us.

Comment: Unfortunately, i already modified the code before i read your comment. My code now works fine. It goes like this: `let updatedItem = await Item.findOne({name: req.body.itemName})` `updatedItem.set(key, val);` `updatedItem.save()`. I don't remember what my code was before so i just have to let it down until i encounter it the next time.